# Spark Cassandra Connector - perPartitionLimit

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax

Is there a way in the spark cassandra connector to achieve the **side side filtering** that is equivalent to **per partition limit in cql** or **perPartitionLimit** in the native cassandra java driver?

Note that here it is **limit per cassandra partition** not per spark partition (which is supported by the existing limit function in the connector).

spark 2.0.1, connector - 2.0.0-M3

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the initial answer from RussS.  I got it to work by using the following:

First, we need to use "PER PARTITION LIMIT".

Second, if you have other where clauses, this needs to be combined with one of them, as follows:

sc.cassandraTable(...).where("event_type = 1 PER PARTITION LIMIT 5")

instead of

sc.cassandraTable(...).where("event_type = 1).where("PER PARTITION LIMIT 5")

Otherwise an AND keyword will be generated before "PER PARTITION LIMIT", which will cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

The Spark Cassandra Connector built in limit API (as of 2.0.0-M3) can only limit by C* Token Range.

If you are using Cassandra greater than 3.6 you can manually add a per partition limit in the `.where` API.

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7017

```
sc.cassandraTable(...).where("PER PARTITION LIMIT 10")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  But when it is specified in the where api, the keyword STATICLIMIT is treated as a column name, hence an error.

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Exception during preparation of SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE token("src") > ? AND token("src") <= ? AND STATICLIMIT = 1 AND event_type = 1   ALLOW FILTERING: Undefined column name staticlimit.

Cassandra version 3.9

Comment: Ah sorry didn't read the end of that ticket. PER PARTITION LIMIT